# Android 3d animation like Google Now Launcher Menu Animation

Tags: android, animation, 3d

I need to make animation between Activities or Fragments like this. I use `Android Api >=14.`

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNMqIv5Ocnk - it's Nexus5 Launcher

I`ve already tried animation with Android ObjectAnimator, but it wasn't very similar to this video animation.

Thanks in advance.

I`ve tried this code

**(gla_on.xml):**

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0" />
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="12" />
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="12" />
```

**gla_off.xml:**

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0" />
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="12" />
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="12" />
```

**and put it into this fragment of code:**

```
getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.gla_on, R.anim.gla_off)
        .replace(R.id.container, new NextFragment())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

but NextFragment doesn't show

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**CLOSED**

After many attempts I found the decision.

(You can watch the result here - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Npn0c68OkYs )

I create 4 animations in Android Resource folder *anim*

**gla_there_come.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1" />

</set>
```

**gla_there_gone.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="12" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="12" />

</set>
```

**gla_back_gone.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="12"
        android:valueTo="1" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="12"
        android:valueTo="1" />

</set>
```

**gla_back_come.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0" />

</set>
```

and I added **the code below into my FragmentActivity:**

```
public void goToNext() {
    mShowingNext = true;

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.gla_there_come, R.anim.gla_there_gone)
            .replace(R.id.container, new NextFragment())
            .commit();
}

public void goBack() {
    mShowingNext = false;

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.gla_back_gone, R.anim.gla_back_come)
            .replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: This won't work with me , I changed the anim directory to animator and the recourse now is R.animator.gla_there_come