# Android Fragment Transaction custom Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to achieve the animation found here.

[Android 3d animation like Google Now Launcher Menu Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296910/android-3d-animation-like-google-now-launcher-menu-animation/22334945#22334945)

However, it looks like I can not use the objectAnimator because I'm using the Support Library Fragments.  When I tried using the code at the above link, I got an error stating that Unknown animation: objectAnimator.

How can I accomplish an animation like this when adding/removing fragments while still using the Support Library for Fragments?

**UPDATE**

As per the answer from DeeV below, I've updated the XML Animations for the rest.

**gla_back_come.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:duration="500">

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" />

</set>
```

**gla_back_gone.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:duration="500" >

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="12.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="12.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

**gla_there_come.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:duration="500">

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

**gla_there_gone.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:duration="500" >

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"/>

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="12.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="12.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used basic animations, but I believe the interpolators need to be taken from the "@android:anim/" folder and they're all post-fixed with "_interpolator".  They're essentially the same things, but they may not exist at the "@android:interpolator/" location in younger devices.  I edited my answer with the `accelarate_decelerate_interpolator` one.

Comment: @DeeV - thank you !  I'll update my XML above to match.

Comment: @DeeV - can you check my updated XML for the gla_back_gone and gla_back_come animations?  They don't seem to be doing what the video example did.  I think I may have something wrong

Comment: I haven't validated how the animations work. The assumption was the animations in the answer you posted were correct. I'm just saying how you use Animations with support fragments.

Comment: @DeeV - so the way I converted them looks correct?  That's what I was asking.  Regardless of if the original animations are correct, are my conversions to use the old Animations good?

Comment: The only odd thing is I notice he doesn't use the pivot. It's used to expand/shrink the view at different points of the View. Maybe it's not needed for what you're trying to do. Maybe remove it and go with default. What is different from the expected result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117754/discussion-between-phil-and-deev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would replace the `ObjectAnimator` with the classic [Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View).  They can be created in roughly the same fashion.  Instead of putting the xml files in the `animator` resource directory, you would put them in the `anim` resource directory.  The Animations themselves in the xml file are more specificly named.  Instead of naming out properties, you name the animation you want to perform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@[package:]anim/interpolator_resource"
    android:shareInterpolator=["true" | "false"] >
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="float"
        android:toAlpha="float" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="float"
        android:toXScale="float"
        android:fromYScale="float"
        android:toYScale="float"
        android:pivotX="float"
        android:pivotY="float" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="float"
        android:toXDelta="float"
        android:fromYDelta="float"
        android:toYDelta="float" />
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="float"
        android:toDegrees="float"
        android:pivotX="float"
        android:pivotY="float" />
    <set>
        ...
    </set>
</set>
```

So for example in the answer you posted, the "gla_there_come.xml" would go from this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <objectAnimator
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0" />
  <objectAnimator
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1" />
  <objectAnimator
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1" />

</set>
```

to this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     duration="500">

  <alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

  <scale
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

Comment: thanks!  If you have a minute and can add the conversion for the others that would be great!  If not, no worries.